Update / insert a document in Elastic
I have an Elasticsearch index where I want to insert or update a document.
My plan is as follows:

If the document does not exist, create a document with a specific ID and add the specified parameters.
If the document does exist, retain all the existing fields and add or update the specified field.

I experimented with the upsert function but without success. I am using PHP and the Elastic ClientBuilder. My code correctly indexes a document when it's new. However, when I tried implementing the upsert function, it updated the document correctly but also deleted all the existing fields, only leaving the newly specified field.
This code works for inserting a document:
$ID = "XYZ";
$output = array("field1" => 1, "field2" => 2);
$params = [
  'index' => 'dataindex',
  'id' => $ID,
  'body' => $output,
];

$response = $client->index($params);

Now, I want to update the field 2 value from 2 to 3. I tried the upsert function, but it did not work. One thing that could be problematic, which is probably why it did not work, is that several fields are saved for each document, not just 2, as shown above. Say there are 15 of them. However, not all documents will have all the fields. So when updating a document, I want to update the field value passed during that update and leave all the other existing fields as they are, given I do not know which other fields are present in that document.
Can I insert/update a document as I need within one query? And if not, what would be the correct way?

I tried the upsert function, but it did not work. We cannot diagnose "did not work". You need to show (1) what you did (2) what outcome you got (3) how that differed from your expectations.
